# With jQuery, what is the point of encapsulating a function in round brackets?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I see this in some HTML files that use jQuery, at the bottom:

```
(function() {
        setTimeout(function(){window.scrollTo(0,0);},0);
    })();
```

What does it mean to put the whole function in round brackets?

Comment: It's to make the function asynchronous so it scrolls smoother ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you gave as example is a self-executing anonymous function.

You can read more about them [here](http://markdalgleish.com/2011/03/self-executing-anonymous-functions/).

Relevant text from that article:

> What’s useful here is that JavaScript has function level scoping. All variables and functions defined within the anonymous function aren’t available to the code outside of it, effectively using closure to seal itself from the outside world.

Answer (score 2):

(`function() {})();` means it is self executing anonymous function. It get called immediately when java script get rendered. More details you can search it.

Answer (score -1):

`setTimeout` is a function which accepts two parameters:

First parameter: A function

Second parameter: an integer value in milliseconds.

By calling the setTimeout function, the function from first parameter will be called/invoked after the amount of time specified in the second parameter.

Comment: He is asking about the part `(function() { ... })()`, not about `setTimeout` :)

Comment: Oh yes, I get it. Sorry for misunderstanding.